# How to use Google Data Prep API using Python

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer, google-cloud-dataprep

Google Just launched the new API. Link is [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/API-Workflow---Run-Job_145281449).

I want to know what is the host in this case as they are using `example.com` and using the `port 3005`.

I am also following [this article](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/how-to-orchestrate-cloud-dataprep-jobs-using-cloud-composer). But this does not provide example code.

Answer (score 4):

If you open the Dataprep Console and navigate to `Settings > Access Tokens` you can click on `Generate New Token`. This will bring up the token, that you can copy to clipboard, but also the instructions on which base endpoint to use:

---

[image]

Then, clicking on a particular Recipe (see image below) will modify the browser URL to be in the form of:

```
https://clouddataprep.com/flows/<FLOW_ID>?recipe=<RECIPE_ID>&tab=recipe
```

[image]

We'll keep `RECIPE_ID>` so that our request body (`dataprep-request.json`) is something like this:

```js
{
  "wrangledDataset": {
    "id": <RECIPE_ID>
  }
}
```

Then, we can call [`JobGroups Create`](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/API-JobGroups-Create-v4_145281446):

```sh
curl https://api.clouddataprep.com/v4/jobGroups \
  -X POST \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d @dataprep-request.json
```

The response will be similar to this output (I used `python3 -m json.tool` to pretty print the JSON):

```js
{
    "sessionId": "<SESSION_ID>",
    "reason": "JobStarted",
    "jobGraph": {
        "vertices": [
            4479390,
            4479391
        ],
        "edges": [
            {
                "source": 4479390,
                "target": 4479391
            }
        ]
    },
    "id": <JOB_GROUP_ID>,
    "jobs": {
        "data": [
            {
                "id": 4479390
            },
            {
                "id": 4479391
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Now, with the retrieved `<JOB_GROUP_ID>` we can use the [`JobGroups Get`](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/API-JobGroups-Get-v4_145281447) endpoint:

```sh
curl https://api.clouddataprep.com/v4/jobGroups/<JOB_GROUP_ID> \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN"
```

Response:

```js
{
    "id": <JOB_GROUP_ID>,
    "name": null,
    "description": null,
    "ranfrom": "ui",
    "ranfor": "recipe",
    "status": "InProgress",
    "profilingEnabled": true,
    "runParameterReferenceDate": "2019-12-08T21:49:33.000Z",
    "createdAt": "2019-12-08T21:49:35.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2019-12-08T21:49:36.000Z",
    "workspace": {
        "id": REDACTED
    },
    "creator": {
        "id": REDACTED
    },
    "updater": {
        "id": REDACTED
    },
    "snapshot": {
        "id": 4226057
    },
    "wrangledDataset": {
        "id": <RECIPE_ID>
    },
    "flowRun": null
}
```